# One Domain with Multiple War

Tags: java, spring

I have Two spring MVC web application(app1.war & app2.war), and both share the same DB.
Now I want host them on any cloud based hosting site(openshift, amazon etc.).
Here I want to host both inside **one domain**.

suppose my host name is - www.abc.com
so

- **abc.com** --> will refer app1
- **spath**.abc.com --> will refer app2

Please let me know, if it can possible,And How It can be done. Also where any hosting site also supporting this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with java or spring.  This is more or less related to how to configure DNS.. and maybe your web server if you're hosting both on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by configuring your domain properly.

Note that **abc.com** and **spath.abc.com** can be used to run two different websites. You will need to configure your domain's CNAME section and add a sub-domain there.

Once that is done you can configure Apache Tomcat's Host Name. Taking DigitalOcean as your cloud provider, you can configure this easily by changing Tomcat configuration.

You can then point **abc.com** to your `app1.war` and **spath.abc.com** to `app2.war`

Kindly comment if you face any issues. I'll be happy to help you out here.

Comment: Thanks Jagjot, I will try.Also I want app2 war secure https so app1=http www.abc.com/ and app2=https spath.abc.com/.Is it possible on suggested approach right?

Comment: @Manu Yes it is also possible with this approach.